# How to change the glow outline color of a focused text field in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

After alot of browsing I haven't yet found a solution to this.

I'm trying to change `this really light blue-ish border color` around the `TextFiedl` (when it's selected).

---

The closest I've been to was with this:
[image]

```
.text-field {
    -fx-faint-focus-color: red;
}
```

But I get this result:

[image]

A really strong tone of red (the complete opposite of that soft border), that also looks thicker than the original one.

---

So, how can I change **just** the color, so that instead of a very light blue I'd be able to get, say, a very light red, whilst keeping the thickness/overall feel of the original glow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried to reduce the alpha :

```css
.text-field:focused{
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-focus-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.2); /* here rgba (corrected) */
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The default `-fx-faint-focus-color` has a opacity of `0x22` / `0xFF`. You should do the same and also set the `-fx-focus-color` to `red`:

```css
.text-field {
    -fx-focus-color: red;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: #ff000022;
}
```

---

default values from `modena.css`:

```css
-fx-focus-color: #039ED3;
-fx-faint-focus-color: #039ED322;
```

Comment: putting these in `.root` works like a charm for "any focused" control

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the code below:

```
.text-field{
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box, red , 10.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0);
    -fx-background-insets:3.0;
    -fx-background-radius: 5.0;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill:black;
    -fx-text-fill:black;
    -fx-font-size:12.0;
    -fx-font-weight:bold; 

}


.text-field:focused{
    -fx-background-color: firebrick;
    -fx-text-fill:white;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill:white;
    -fx-background-insets: -0.1, 2.0;
    -fx-font-size:14.0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: People who make  ... -1. At least let me know what was wrong . We are here to improve .